# increase md-icon size inside md-menu

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm writing the client side of my web site in angularjs 1.5.0 with angular-material.

I want to have a button that opens a popup menu. the problem that i've been having is that the icon appears really small and i don't know how to increase it's size.

this is the $mdIconProvider configuration:

```
app.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
    // Configure URLs for icons specified by [set:]id.
    $mdIconProvider
        .icon('menu', 'svg/menu.svg');
});
```

and this is the code for the menu icon and the popup menu:

```
<md-menu id="mainmenu" md-position-mode="target-right target">
<md-button aria-label="Open demo menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
    <md-icon md-menu-origin md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon>
</md-button>
<md-menu-content width="4">
    <md-menu-item>
       <md-button ng-click="changePage('/')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Home</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/home.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item ng-show="!isAuthenticated()">
       <md-button ng-click="changePage('/login')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Login</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/home.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>

      <md-menu-item ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('inventory')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Inventory</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/inventory.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
      <md-menu-item ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('add-drink')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Ad Drink</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/add_drink.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
          </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('add-cocktail')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Add Cocktail</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/add_cocktail.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
                 <md-menu-item ng-show="isUserGroupAllowed(1)">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('admin-generic-drinks')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Admin Generic Drinks</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/admin_cocktails.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
                     </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item ng-show="isUserGroupIdAllowed(1)">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('admin-drinks')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Admin Drinks</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/admin_cocktails.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
         <md-menu-item ng-show="isUserGroupIdAllowed(1)">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('admin-cocktails')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Admin Cocktails</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/admin_cocktails.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
     <md-menu-item ng-show="isUserGroupIdAllowed(1)">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('admin-glasses')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Admin Glasses</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/admin_cocktails.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
     <md-menu-item ng-show="isUserGroupIdAllowed(1)">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('admin-pending-images')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Admin Pending Images</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/admin_pending_images.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
    <md-menu-item ng-show="isAuthenticated()">
        <md-button ng-click="changePage('logout')">
            <div layout="row">
                <p flex>Logout</p>
                <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="svg/logout.svg" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
            </div>
        </md-button>
    </md-menu-item>
</md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

so.... how do I increase the md-icon size ?

Comment: Can you make a plunker?

Comment: @AmitSirohiya - it's the top right icon on my website at https://myalcoholist.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide height and width in css or  [apply this setting](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdIconProvider) or [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/icon)

Comment: unfortunately inside the md-menu when i try to increase the icon size, it gets hidden.

Comment: you need to override .md-button.md-icon-button like this   
   .md-button.md-icon-button{
    height: 64px;   
    width: 64px;
    border-radius:0px  
}   http://codepen.io/ktn/pen/EKyYrz

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are built in md-xx classes that will allow you to size an icon, e.g md-48.

See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3776) for further info

Comment: hi! i checked the issue and there isn't a built in md-48. increasing the icon size inside md-menu doesn't work properly. it gets hidden.